# Knp paginator bundle doesnt work perfectly when switching pages symfony 3?

Tags: php, pagination, twig, symfony

i have installed the knp paginator bundle in my project and i followed the installation tuto in git hub and then every thing work but there is a problem  in my controller i fixed the limit per page to 1 item and i find when im switching page it shows me 2 items

this is my controller

```
public function membreGroupeAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $str = $em->getRepository("GroupGroupBundle:Groupe")->findOneBy(array('id'=>1));
    $member = $em->getRepository("GroupGroupBundle:Groupe")->getmemberlist($str->getMembres());

    $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $res = $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $member, /* query NOT result */
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),       /*page number*/
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1)        /*limit per page*/
    );


    return $this->render('@GroupGroup/layout/membres.html.twig',array("mem"=>$res));

}
```

and this is my twig view

```
 {% extends '@GroupGroup/Group/groupe_mur_base.html.twig' %}
 {% block panel %}

<div class="jumbotron list-content" style="display: block;">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li href="#" class="list-group-item title">
            Liste des Membres
        </li>
        {% for i in  mem %}
            <li href="#" class="list-group-item text-left" id="listmembre" style="display: block;">

                <div class="image">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{ i.profile_pic }}">
                    <span id="membername">{{ i.nom }} {{ i.prenom }}</span>
                    <div><button id="btnajout" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button></div>

                </div>
                <div class="break"></div>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}




        <li href="#" class="list-group-item text-left">
            <div class="navigation text-center" >
                {{ knp_pagination_render(mem) }}
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
  {% endblock %}
```

this is my output in the first page
[image: first page]

and this is my output after clicking to the 2nd page
[image: 2nd page output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't setting the limit to 1, you are setting it to the current page.

```
$res = $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $member, /* query NOT result */
    $request->query->getInt('page', 1),       /*page number*/
    $request->query->getInt('page', 1) // <-- right here
);
```

Change the marked line to just `1` and you should be fine.

Comment: oooo thnks a lot really i didnt get it at the first time thnks man

Comment: i got an error message at the bottom of my project its said translation or something like that what caused this plzz

Comment: Please create a new question for this, it isn't related to your limit issue.

Comment: i cant post the question now it said you can post only after 90 minutes

Answer (score 0):

this is the right code i found out my error 
everything is working perfectly now

```
$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
    $res = $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $member, /* query NOT result */
        $request->query->getInt('page', 1),       /*page number*/
        $request->query->getInt('limit', 1)        /*limit per page*/
    );
```